# MariaDB messages when stopping/starting any service

Tags: sockets, mariadb

We have:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster
x86_64
Linux 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

When starting/stopping mariadb.service, the following message appears:

```
Failed to get properties: Unit name mariadb-extra@.socket is neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name.
Failed to get properties: Unit name mariadb@.socket is neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name.
```

The same messages pop up when starting/stopping any service.

What's wrong with mariadb user sockets? How can I remove these messages?

Comment: A couple more points. Sockets are disabled, I found a mention of this in the /var/log/apt/term.log:

New version of the configuration file is installed  /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf …
mariadb-extra.socket is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
mariadb-extra.socket is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.

A similar error appears on 2 machines - a remote VDS with Debian 10 and a Windows 10 Hyper-V virtual machine with Debian 10 installed on it. This means that this behavior of mariadb is typical.

Comment: Any progress on this?
I got same messages when executing `service mysql/mariadb start/stop`,
but when I use `systemctl start/stop mysql/mariadb`, it didn't appear.

Comment: My env is fresh installed `Ubuntu 18.04.6`, `MariaDB 10.6.7 /w Galera 4`

Answer (score 2):

From [MDEV-27715](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27715), the `service` implementation of Debian/Ubuntu is deficient in that it doesn't fully understand socket templated files of systemd.

Use `systemctl`.